# CSS pulse animation override on hover

Tags: css, css-animations, scale, pause, pulse

I have a pulsing circle that needs to be able to stop pulsing on hover, but then scale to the correct size.

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.33);
    }
}

.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #f0f;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
    &:hover{
        transform: scale(1.33);
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
}
```

what i would like it to do is on hover scale to the correct size from where ever it is in the animation.

i.e. if it is currently scale(1.2) on the downsize, go back up to scale(1.33) on hover.

**-- note: this should transition, not just snap to that size.**

is this possible with css? do i need to work out some other wizardry?

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andeh/f81460a9/) for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the `scale(1)` from `100%`. You also don't need to pause the animation

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.33);
  }
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #f0f;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.33);
  /* animation-play-state: paused; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

An idea in order to have a transition:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.33);
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
}
.circle::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #f0f;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.33);
  transition:1s;
}
.circle:hover::before {
  animation: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again a good solution for stopping the overriding animation and appreciate the cleanup of code in the mean time, but i need it to transition to this state too, not just change to it

Comment: @AndrewGordon you cannot with your actual code, Are you ready for some complex one?

Comment: Thats awesome, but nooooot quite what i need unfortunately. It needs to animate from the size it currently is. 
- i'm happy for some super complex javascript fun, was hoping it might be possible with CSS. this is to be built in React so was hoping for an easier solution lol

Comment: ideally it would also start pulsing from the large size again rather than snapping back to 100%. This is why originally i thought Pause might be an ok solution, but it doesn't quite work like i hoped.

Comment: @AndrewGordon it's impossible with CSS, even with JS you will need some complex code

Comment: so ive kinda faked it using your example. Ive stick with the fact that it snaps, which is a little disappointing, however ive put a delay on the pulse to begin with. This allows a user to hover straight away and its smooth, when they mouse off it animates back to how it was.
[check the jsfiddle now](https://jsfiddle.net/andeh/f81460a9) 
Thanks alot for your help, its the best solution i have without exploding javascript and jquery librarys :)

Answer (score 0):

Animation properties will always override normal properties. You can use a CSS variable to override animation property.

`var(--expected-variable-if-exist, default)`

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(var(--scale, 1));
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(var(--scale, 1.33));
  }
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #f0f;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.circle:hover {
  --scale: 1.33;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can that transition though, rather than just snap. Thats an extended issue i have. - lovely solution though!